# Prevent Flex-wrap 3:1 case

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm sorry I don't know how to write the right question. But here's the problem I want to solve:

If the container have 4 items, and each item has Flex:1 --> then it will position the items through the order: 1 row with 4 items --> 2 rows with 3 items in row 1 and 1 big item in row 2 ---> 2 rows with 2 items ---> and 4 rows.

Is there any way that I can prevent the case '2 rows, with 3 items in row 1 and 1 big item in row 2'? (the second case)

Same case with a container with 6 items, 8 items,... and so on....

Here's the example:

[image: Example]

Thank you very much.

Comment: Uh...can you mock up a graphical representation of what you mean by this, in Paint or something? Some people may find your listing of row/item combinations to be...well, confusing.

Comment: Hi, I added a photo as example for the problem. :)

Comment: Ah, that helps clear up some details - can you supply a snippet of your code that recreates the situation? It's much easier to propose solutions to a problem if they include a [mcve].

Comment: It always happen when you choose flex-wrap: wrap on the parent div and flex: 1 on the childrens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most simple and elegant solution might be to wrap each two items in separate flex-container with no `flex-wrap: wrap;`:

```css
.flex-outer {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

/* no row-wrapping here */
/* just leave it with default flex-wrap: nowrap */
.flex-inner {
  display: flex;
}

/* Just styles for demo */
.flex-item {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: orange;
  color: white;
  font-size: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-outer">
  <div class="flex-inner">
    <div class="flex-item">
      One
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
      Two
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-inner">
    <div class="flex-item">
      Three
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
      Four
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want items to take all remaining space, set `flex: 1;` for `.flex-item` and `.flex-inner`.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved what you need this way...
First I applied flex declarations to the div that wraps your images.

```
<div class="wrap">

    <p>picture</p>
    <p>picture</p>
    <p>picture</p>
    <p>picture</p>

</div>

.wrap {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-flow: wrap;
    -webkit-flex-flow: wrap;
    flex-flow: wrap;
}
```

Then I used flex property which is a shorthand for flex: (flex-grow) (flex-shrink) (flex-basis). Note that flex-basis is set to 50%. That means that element will take half of the viewport.

```
.wrap p {
    flex: 0 0 50%;
    -webkit-flex: 0 0 50%;
    -ms-flex: 0 0 50%;
}
```